# .replace() em objeto jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho um código que recebe um valor de um campo em HTML. Eu igualo o valor de uma variável ao objeto em jQuery, e em seguida uso o valor colocado lá para fazer algumas comparações de `>=` ou `<=`.

Eu quero colocar uma máscara de CEP no local, porém o traço (`99999-999`) corta o valor numérico do CEP aos primeiros 5 dígitos. Fiz o seguinte código para poder tirar esse traço da jogada e mexer apenas com os números do CEP, mas por algum motivo não funciona:

```
var cep = parseInt($('#ip-cep').val.toString().replace(/-/, ''), 10);
```

Só pra esclarecer, eu pego o valor do campo HTML, transformo em string, retiro o traço com `.replace()`, e então converto de volta em numeral para fazer as comparações.

A questão é que não funciona. O valor de `cep` sempre retorna como `NaN`, mesmo com a entrada de valores apenas numéricos. Se eu tiro o traço com o `replace`, quando o `parseInt` entra em ação só deveria haver números no local para serem convertidos, já que a máscara só permite que o usuário digite números.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Está usando o `.val` de forma errônea. A sintaxe correta é `.val()`:

```js
var cep = parseInt($('#ip-cep').val().toString().replace(/-/, ''), 10);
console.log(cep);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="ip-cep" value="71000-123">
```

Answer (score 0):

Opa, 
    Verifiquei aqui e testei com uma variável local,
    Depois peguei o valor com teu próprio código para testar, e funcionou! (pode executar no browser para testar, basta apertar F12 e ir para o Console)

```
var testeCep = '99999-999';
var cep = parseInt(testeCep.toString().replace(/-/, ''), 10);
```

Ou seja, o problema está no método em que tu pega o valor, que ao invés de .val, seria .value (sem parenteses), espero que tenha ajudado! Segue o código abaixo testado abraços!

```
var cep = parseInt($('#ip-cep').value.toString().replace(/-/, ''), 10);
console.log(cep);
```