# Como fazer o replace no JQuery ou Javascript de uma string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho a mensagem "**-** Deseja realmente transferir as perguntas do..."

Como faço para remover (replace) do início de uma mensagem o traço "-" ?

Segue a função que imprime a mensagem:

```
                        function closePopup11110() {
                            $("[id$='textoMensagem11110']").html('#{msg.MN067}');
                            $(".dialog11110").dialog('close');
                        }
```

Comment: Possível [duplicata](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/293771/replace-em-objeto-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para substituir usando [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), basta passar o valor que quer ser substituído por um **novo** valor ou **nenhum**, se quiser também retirar o espaço que fica no começo do texto pode usar o método [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim):

```js
let texto = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].textContent;   // pega o texto
let novo = texto.replace('-', '');                               // substiui - por vazio

console.log(texto);                                              // texto original
console.log(novo);                                               // texto novo
console.log(novo.trim());                                        // sem espaço
```

```html
<p>- Deseja realmente transferir as perguntas do...</p>
```

Comment: LeAndrade, apliquei sua solução e funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado pelo apoio!

Comment: Legal man, suceso aí!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode remover apenas o primeiro caractere usando substring:

```
let string = $("[id$='textoMensagem11110']").text();
string = string.substring(1);
$("[id$='textoMensagem11110']").html(string);
```

Vale ressaltar que o método `text` vai ler todo o conteúdo do seu elemento, então você deve mudar o seletor pra pegar apenas a mensagem correta.

Comment: Entendi @ayrton, mas em qual momento faço o replace para remover o traço no início da frasa "- Deseja realmente transferir as perguntas do..."?

Comment: Antes de transplantar ela pro html (que seria a linha 3 do código que eu coloquei)